# plotting a curve in MATLAB with prefefined x-axis

Tags: matlab, plot

I have two vectors:

**x** = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 20, 50, 100]

and

**y**=[7, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1];

I am interested to plot Y as a function of X in MATLAB. So, this can be done by:

```
figure;
plot(x, y, '--rs');
```

In fact, the code above plots the curve, but the x-axis seems to be spaced as follows: 0, 10, 20, ..., 100.

What I want is to draw a curve which exhibits just the values in **x** as x-axis and their corresponding y-axis values. An example of x-axis is shown in the picture below.
[image]

Any help will be very appreciated!!

Comment: Does using `set(gca,'XTick',[(1:6) 10 20 50 100])` does what you want or you really want the xticks to be spaced at regular intervals?

Comment: yes but I want that the values in the x-axis be equally spaced. And their corresponding values in the y-axis be very clear. So one can clearly read the curve and see what is the y point for every x point. Thank you very much

Comment: alright please see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of plotting using `plot(x,y)`, use `plot(1:numel(x),y)` and use the `XTick` and XTickLabels` properties to change the labelling of the graph to suit your need.

Example:

```
clc
clear

x = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 20, 50, 100];

y=[7, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1];

plot(1:numel(x),y,'--rs')

set(gca, 'XTick', 1:length(x)); %// Change x-axis ticks
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', x); %// Change x-axis ticks labels.
```

Result:

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you sooo much